# Condition with mysql request

Tags: mysql, node.js

I have a problem for my image (I use multer), when in my user edit form.
Is it possible to put conditions on my image if the field is null, it still sends my request to the server.
I did the necessary on the front-end to send the firstname and lastname data but for the image impossible, that's why I want to go through the back end.

```
exports.updateUser = (req, res, next) => {
    try {
        if (res.locals.userId === parseInt(req.params.id)) {
            const user = [
                [req.body.user_lastName],
                [req.body.user_firstName],
                [`${req.protocol}://${req.get('host')}/images/${req.file.filename}`],
                [req.params.id]
            ]
            const sql = "UPDATE users SET user_lastName=?, user_firstName=?,user_avatar=? WHERE user_id=?";
            db.query(sql, user, function (error, results) {
                if (!error) {
                    res.status(200).json({ message: 'modification profil executé' });
                } else {
                    console.log(error)
                    res.status(401).json({ error: 'Erreur utilisateur table users' });
                }
            });

        } else {
            res.status(401).json({ error: 'erreur d\'authentification, vous n\'avez pas les droits pour modifier ce profil' })
        }
    } catch (error) {
        res.status(500).json({ error });
        console.log(error)
    }
}
```

Comment: Which field are you talking about?

Comment: FYI, you don't need to put each element of `user` in a nested array.

Answer (score 0):

Use an `if` statement to set a variable conditional on whether the field was provided.

```js
exports.updateUser = (req, res, next) => {
  try {
    let image = null;
    if (req.?file.?filename) {
      image = `${req.protocol}://${req.get('host')}/images/${req.file.filename}`;
    }
    if (res.locals.userId === parseInt(req.params.id)) {
      const user = [
        req.body.user_lastName,
        req.body.user_firstName,
        image,
        req.params.id
      ]
      const sql = "UPDATE users SET user_lastName=?, user_firstName=?,user_avatar=? WHERE user_id=?";
      db.query(sql, user, function(error, results) {
        if (!error) {
          res.status(200).json({
            message: 'modification profil executé'
          });
        } else {
          console.log(error)
          res.status(401).json({
            error: 'Erreur utilisateur table users'
          });
        }
      });

    } else {
      res.status(401).json({
        error: 'erreur d\'authentification, vous n\'avez pas les droits pour modifier ce profil'
      })
    }
  } catch (error) {
    res.status(500).json({
      error
    });
    console.log(error)
  }
}
```

Comment: i have a error with '?',but I understood what to do, thank you